# How to avoid tkinter's IntVar.get() raising TclError on blank strings

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got an `Entry` tied to an `IntVar`, but calling `my_int_var.get()` throws an exception that seems to complain that the variable is an empty string. I only expect integers to be input by the user in that field.

Is there a better solution besides catching `TclError`?

Here's the traceback I'm trying to avoid:

```
|| Traceback (most recent call last):
||   File "Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
||     return self.func(*args)
||   File "/gui.py", line 172, in callback
||     print(f"Value is now: {my_int_var.get()}")
||   File "Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 507, in get
||     return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
|| _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

This is triggered on a callback tied to the `my_int_var`'s `.trace()` call. The exception is thrown when you erase the content of the `Entry` by selecting all the text with a mouse and hitting backspace, leading to a blank value.

Here's some code you can run yourself to reproduce the issue, without having to use the mouse:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
my_int_var = tk.IntVar()

entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=my_int_var)
entry.delete(0, tk.END)

my_int_var.get() #throws TclError
```

Comment: post the code to get answer

Comment: I'll add a simple repro, thanks

Comment: @ADWAN Added, check it out

Comment: What is a better solution depends on what you want to achieve. It is not clear why you tied the `Entry` to an `IntVar` if you expect it to hold non-integer values.

Comment: @Goyo I'm using `Entry` since I understood it to be the easiest way to let someone type and erase an integer. I only want to use integers in the `Entry`. If there's a better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: If you want to let the user erase the content then you cannot have only integers. If you want to have only integers then you can't let the user erase the content. You can't have both at the same time. An empty string is not the representation of an integer.

Comment: @Goyo Is there a way to do that? Seems strange that you're not able to use an `Entry` for numbers like that. How do you handle someone backspacing away the digit there and starting a new one? Short of using insert mode, I'm not sure there's an answer for that, is there?

Comment: It's up to you how to handle it. You can't expect tkinter to know how to convert an empty string to a number, just like you don't expect `int('')` to return a number.

Comment: @Goyo that's a bummer, so there's no way to check the contents of the entry to make sure that its a valid number without catching the TclError.  You could add that as an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: Of course there are several ways to safely check the contents. For instance you can use `Entry.get` .

Comment: @Goyo That makes sense, so you need to track the entry, then check the value for empty string, then go to the variable and get the number from there. Not optimal, but I appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving the error because the variable is empty. You can set the initial value to 0 to prevent this error using:

```
var.set(0)
```

And also, you don't need to delete the data from the entry, because when an entry is created, it is empty. So remove line:

```
entry.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Here is a code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=var)
var.set(0)    #<--  Set the value to 0

var.get() #<-- Working
```

**Edit:**

You can use the `try`/`except` statement. Here is a working of the statements:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=var)
entry.pack()
var.set(0)    #<--  Set the value to 0
def _get():
    try:var.get()
    except:var.set(0)

tk.Button(text="Press",command=_get).pack()
root.mainloop()
#var.get() #<-- Working
```

When you press the button, if the entry is empty, its value will be set to 0.

Comment: I didn't explain the issue well enough. When you erase the contents of an `Entry` via the GUI, by backspacing it all, the contents of the `Entry` become the empty string, leading to my question. I'll try to clarify what I meant in the OP, thanks!

Comment: @TankorSmash Check now

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! I think that might be a solution, however non-ideal: waiting for a button press to trigger the read of the value. I must be using Entry and IntVar wrong though, because this seems like an issue everyone would be running into.